# Own Postgres Type as Alias Array

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I want to create a custom type that is an alias for int[4].

I tried the following statements:

```
create type rect as int[4];
```

> Syntax error near "int"

```
create type rect as (int[4]);
```

> Syntax error near [

In the documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtype.html) i also couldn't find anything about creating "alias" data types.

Whats the correct syntax here?
I am running Postgres 9.6beta4

Comment: You are looking for a domain: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks!